# Does USB-C Alternate Mode require the Billboard Device to be always connected?

Tags: usb-c, displayport

I'm working on a device design that operates in USB-C alternate mode as a displayport dongle.  As such it requires a USB 2.0 billboard device to be present to negotiate with the host and enter alt mode.

This might be a silly question but if after the device enters alt mode, I want to turn the USB 2.0 connection over to another device (using a USB Mux), can I disconnect the billboard and then point to my other USB device without losing Alt Mode function?  Or will alt mode cease function when the Billboard is disconnected?

In the USB-C Spec from August 2019, the following is stated

*E.4.3 Operational Summary:*

*Host stays in USB DisplayPort Dock mode until*

*a. Explicitly exited by and Exit Mode VDM.*

*b. System physically disconnected from the USB DisplayPort Dock*

*c. Hard Reset on USB PD*

*d. VBus is removed*

Would (b) count as physical device removal?  Or is it referring to the USB-C connection and not the USB 2.0 Billboard Interface?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following in the USB-C R2.0 Spec 2019:

> When a device offers multiple modes, especially where multiple
>   Alternate Mode definitions are needed in order to be compatible with
>   multiple host-side implementations, successfully entering an Alternate
>   Mode may be predicated on only one of the available modes being
>   successfully recognized by a host.  In this case, the device is not
>   required to expose but may still expose a USB Billboard Device
>   Classinterface to indicate to the host the availability and status of
>   the modes it supports.
>
> The host may send an Enter Mode after tAMETimeout.  If the device
>   enters the mode, it shall respond with an ACK and discontinue exposing
>   the USB Billboard Device Classinterface.  The device may expose the
>   USB Billboard Device Classinterface again with updated capabilities.

According to this, exposure of the interface after Alternate Mode has been entered is optional, and may be re-exposed later with updated information if need be.  I will take this to mean "Yes, the interface can be disconnected" after Alternate Mode entry.